# Partition an array into equal size subsets that satisfy a condition

Tags: algorithm, optimization

Let's say you have a 2D array with 96 unique rows consisting of lists of numbers from 1 - 4 of length `d`. e.g.:

```
[[1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4],
 [2, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 1],
 [4, 1, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3],
 [3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1]]
...
]
```

(the entire array can be accessed here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sitNVmdQKhmJGerYHazPe9ygYQpUiMqY/view?usp=sharing)

The task is to split this array into 6 sub-arrays each of shape `(16, d)`. The only condition that needs to be satisfied is that in at least five sub-arrays each column needs to have at least two occurrences of numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4.

---

**My (bad) solutions**

1. I have implemented an algorithm that randomly picks the subsets and checks the condition. It works for smaller arrays but if `d` is larger (e.g. 16 - such as in my case), it is likely a very ineffective approach.
2. I also implemented a greedy approach that first considers all sequences and cycles through all combinations of sub-arrays. If a sub-array that satisfies the condition is found, it is kept and the same thing is done on the rest until you have 5 sub-arrays that satisfy the condition.

I really do not like both implementations and I am sure that there is a more elegant approach.

Comment: The shown rows are not _unique_.

Comment: Is is a possible idea: compute the sorted unique values in each line using `np.unique` and then use a CSP solver to group the values in 4 bins.

Comment: By "splitting" into the sub-matrices with the desired shape, is it that you're reordering the rows of the original matrix (not the columns in any way)? So basically the goal is to reorder the 96 rows such that rows from 0-15 inclusive, 16-31 inclusive, and so on follow the desired column property?

Comment: @wLui155 exactly